# Objects of Java and C++

Tags: java, c++

The Java `Object` has some methods like `toString`, `hashCode`, `equals`, etc. Does an object in C++ have some builtin methods? What are the actual differences between an object in C++ and Java?

Comment: There's no standard class `Object` in C++

Comment: C++ contains some inbuilt methods, all of which can be overridden i.e constructor, destructor, copy constructor, equality operator etc. Java's hashCode, toString don't really have an equivalent in C++ and must be implemented as any other method

Comment: The question seemed valid to me.

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Comment: I guess every time someone has a question touching both Java and C++ everybody is freaking out, fearing for the troll.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: please do **not** put non-code words in code blocks. It's distracting. For plain text formatting, use bold or italics if you must.

Comment: @Mat: in fact, `Object` is a Java `class` :)

Comment: @xtofl: indeed. Notice the formatting.

Answer (score 8):

Things work differently in Java and C++.

- In Java every object inherit from the class `Object`. This is a base class providing some basic member function like `ToString()` that can be overridden by subclasses.
- In C++ there is no such class like `Object`. In fact the word object in C++ refers to any type, including non class type.
  The new C++11 standard provides a standard function `std::to_string` that is valid for any object assuming it exists a valid overload.
  `std::to_string`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string
  `std::hash`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash
  Also equality between any type can be defined through `operator==`

This exhibits a different choice of design between the two languages. While Java is more object oriented ( base classes provide functionality) the C++ standard library uses the generic programming paradigm (algorithms that can be applied to various types).

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you only **pay for what you use**.  Therefore, the default C++ object has no superclass, and no methods pre-defined other than a default constructor, a copy constructor, an assignment operator and a destructor.

Likewise, member methods are not polymorphic by default:

```
class A { void foo(){ cout << "Hello from A\n"; } };
class B : public A { void foo(){ cout << "Hello from B\n";}};

...
unique_ptr<A> a= new B();
a->foo(); // will print Hello from A since a is an A*
```

You need to **declare methods polymorphic** by using the keyword `virtual`:

```
class A { virtual void bar(){ cout << "Hello from A\n"; } };
class B { virtual void bar(){ cout << "BBBB\n";}};

unique_ptr<A> a=new B();
a->bar(); // will print "BBBB": indirection through virtual function table.
```

Classes also get a **destructor**; the lifetime of an object is not limited by it's users/garbage collection, but by it's visibility: an variable no longer visible to any code is cleaned up immediately.

Objects can also be created on the free store by using `new`, in which case they need to be freed explicitly with `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book *Accelerated C++* by Andrew Koenig, the word "object" in C++ can be defined as *'Something which exists in memory'*.   This applies equally to variables of fundamental/primitive types as much as pointers, function pointers, instance objects, arrays, etc.  It is also true irrespective of whether that memory is allocated automatically on the *stack* or dynamically/manually on the *heap*.

This is very different from the definition of the same word in Java where `Object` refers to the ultimate base for all classes, and the word "object" is defined as meaning *'An instance of a class'*; therefore always referring to something allocated on the *heap*.

As the other answers pointed out, C++ does not have any built-in type or ultimate base class called `Object`.

Comment: C++ standard 2011 Section 1.8 "An object is a region of storage"

Answer (score 0):

The methods `toString()`, `hashCode()`, etc are not the standard methods of Java objects, These are the public methods of class `Object` (The supermost class of Java Env.) As every class defaultly extends `Object`, we have these methods in every objects.

But in C++, we don't have any supermost class like `Object` in java, so we don't have any standard methods like these.

Comment: You should use backquotes to delimit code snippets, not boldface.